# Little confused on the thread behaviour

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written a basic code in Thread and the output which i got is pretty surprising.

```
public class ThreadImp implements Runnable{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadImp threadImp = new ThreadImp();
        Thread t =new Thread(threadImp);
        t.setName("Fred");
        t.start();
        threadImp.run();
        t.run();
    
    }
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Current Thread: "+ Thread.currentThread());
    }
}
```

The output here i am expecting is that it will be print

> Current Thread: Thread[main,5,main]
>
> Current Thread: Thread[Fred,5,main]
>
> Current Thread: Thread[main,5,main]

This result i can understand, that there is only one thread which i am creating i.e Thread Fred. Other two calls to run method is just like calling a normal method.

But what i can't understand is sometimes when i execute the same program i am getting the following output. So can anyone explain it to me why is it behaving like this.

> Current Thread: Thread[main,5,main]
>
> Current Thread: Thread[Fred,5,main]

Comment: Behaving like what exactly? That the execution is not consistent?

Comment: add `t.join()` after `t.start()`

Comment: The most important thing to note is that Java is not thread safe which means you shouldn't be designing your program assuming that threads will behave in the same manner every time. The way threads behave could also vary from machine to machine.

Comment: what i was trying to say is that there should be 3 method calls to run method and the print statement should be executed three times. But when i ran it again, the run method was only call twice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You call `Thread.run()` (which you normally shouldn't call directly), and that does nothing if the `Thread` has completed and cleaned itself up:

> ```
> @Override
> public void run() {
>     if (target != null) {
>         target.run();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> *Source: Java 7 update 79*

Where `target` is the provided runnable. The field `target` is set to `null` when the thread has ended:

> ```
> /**
>  * This method is called by the system to give a Thread
>  * a chance to clean up before it actually exits.
>  */
> private void exit() {
>     if (group != null) {
>         group.threadTerminated(this);
>         group = null;
>     }
>     /* Aggressively null out all reference fields: see bug 4006245 */
>     target = null;
>     /* Speed the release of some of these resources */
>     threadLocals = null;
>     inheritableThreadLocals = null;
>     inheritedAccessControlContext = null;
>     blocker = null;
>     uncaughtExceptionHandler = null;
> }
> ```
>
> *Source: Java 7 update 79*

So the exact output (including order, and if you get two or three messages) depends on timing, scheduling, etc.

Comment: The thread does set `null` to `target` when finished running? Can you share the piece of code where it does that?

Comment: @PabloMatiasGomez Added

Comment: Aha!  `It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.`

Comment: @fukanchik Sure, but there is also a difference between `Thread.start()` and `Thread.run()` ;)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you, this solves the doubt i was having.